# Configuration of MySQL Server 5.6.23 is taking longer that expected

Tags: mysql, sql, database, windows, windows-8.1

Having a little trouble finishing the configuration of `MySQL`.  '*Starting server*' has been attempting for about 15-30mins now.  I keep get the following message: Configuration of `MySQL Server 5.6.23` is taking longer that expected.  Do you want to continue waiting or cancel the configuration?

Link of down load: http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/windows/installer/5.6.html

I choose the: `mysql-installer-community`

Because the installer for: `mysql-installer-web-community` was stalling/not responding.

I'm clearly connected to the net.

`MySQL 5.6.23`, `Windows 8.1`,`64 bit`

Link to pic: http://screencast.com/t/0Vhf7JDfb

Suggestions on fixing this issue?

Comment: The installation of MySQL is off topic for SO.  However, you may be able to find help on [su] or [sf].  It is likely however that it is simply a bad connection between you and mysql.com

Comment: @Reed Williams, did you find the solution to overcome this issue ? encounter with this problem as well .i really appreciate if you could help me to figure this out, answering your own question.Thanks

Comment: The same problem here :(